# Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.String. with MySQL VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I don't know why this error still shows up. It says to convert the string but I think it is already in string format. What's the solution to this?

```
Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
    Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet)
    DV.RowFilter = String.Format("emp_no Like '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
End Sub
```

Comment: What data type is `emp_no`?

Comment: If emp_no is a number what is the purpose of searching it with LIKE? So, for example 1 is LIKE 100 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
    Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet)
    DV.RowFilter = String.Format("Convert(emp_no,'System.String') Like '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm. But I have a question. Can I search for multiple columns on a single text box? For example, I can search for both employee number, employee name, and date on it.

Comment: @user3693835 I don't think you can do so, but you can use separate textbox for it.